# run a section of code php file in main file

Tags: php, html, css, jscript

I'm very new to coding.I have a query related to open a php file in another file. I created a php file in the name "sidebarcolumn1.php" and following are the code in the file.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="sidecolumn1">
<div class="box_1b  box_x">
<div class="name_1 round_corner_top">New Categories:</a></div>
<ul class="list_2">
<li><a target="_self" href="/category/Site1/" title="Site1">Site1</a></li>
<li><a target="_self" href="/category/Site2/" title="Site2">Site2</a></li>
<li><a target="_self" href="/category/Site3/" title="Site3">Site3</a></li>
</ul><!--/list_1-->
<div class="slideDown">More [+]</div>
</div><!--/box_1b-->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I want to put it as a small section in main file (index.php) sidebar

How should I call the file in the header?
How should I call it in a section within ? 
How to make it fully functional code for multiple pages (as it is going to remain common for all subpages)?

Answer (score 3):

To include a subpage within a main page, use:

```
include('page_name.php');
```

Comment: Or if you just want to add the html content from that you could use `echo file_get_contents("sidebar.html")`;

Comment: Is your subpage in the same directory as the your main page? Also, make sure your subpage doesn't have `<html>` and `<body>` tags. Only the main page should have those.

Comment: If it's surrounded by html code, be sure to have <?php include('page_name'); ?> or else it won't know that it's actually php code. Also, be sure php is actually installed on the web server.

Comment: no it's not woking I used this ...<?php require('sidecolumn1');?>; this... <?php require('D:\mydocuments\mywebsite\sidecolumn1');?>; this ...<?php require('sidecolumn1.php');?> but none is working. my sidecolumn1.php doesn't contain html or body tags.  any other way to do it

Comment: is there any link to be added in header...like we do in css file?

Comment: actually i'm coding this in dreamweaver. I can see in the design view but when i tried to run in browser. I'm not able to see it

Comment: From your answer above, it looks like you're not set up correctly on your local machine. You need to run a web server (in your case, WAMP is probably the easiest) that can interpret the PHP code. Right now, your browser is just interpreting the PHP as HTML. Alternatively, you could upload all of your code to a web server. If you are in fact using a local web server, you just need to change the include path from `D:\mydocuments...etc` to one relative to the web server root, e.g. `/mysite/sidecolumn1.php` or just `sidecolumn1.php`

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. You can use the `include`

   include('path.php');

2.or the `require`

```
require('path.php');
```

The difference is that, `include`(the page will run even if it cannot locates the file) while the `require` will make an error and will not run if it cannot locates the file

Comment: yes also tried require('sidecolumnbar1.php') but it's not wrkg. do i have to mention entire path...bcoz i did that but it didn't worked. can you tell me what should i add in header to connect to the file?

Comment: are you using this? `<?php include('path.php')`; ?>

Comment: yes I called my file with  <?php include('sidecolumn1.php'); ?>

Comment: actually i'm coding this in dreamweaver. I can see in the design view but when i tried to run in browser. I'm not able to see it

Comment: Since this is PHP, it needs to be interpreted by a preprocessor on a server. You can run one locally (MAMP, WAMP etc.), or upload your files to a server. Only then will you be able to see the `include`d file. You can't just view the `.php` file in your browser locally.